# MKMapView: how can I replicate the 'bounce-zoom' seen in Apple's 'Find my iPhone/Friends' apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

### Background

**[MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/)** comes with several methods that let you set the visible map rect (or region, coordinate span etc). These methods have an *animated* parameter, and when set to true, a linear animation of roughly 0.3 seconds is used to animate the change.

### Question

While this is nice, I'd like to replicate the animation Apple has used in their **Find my Friends** and **Find my iPhone** apps, when tapping on the map. If you try it yourself, you'll notice a much quicker animation (roughly 0.15 seconds) with a non-linear curve. For now, let's call it a 'bounce-zoom' transition.

I'd like to replicate both the non linear animation curve, and custom animation duration. Wrapping map updates in UIView's *animateWithSpring...* method doesn't seem to work (I could be doing it wrong of course). Very aware Apple may have the ability to do things not publicly available in MKMapView's API, however Apple's App Store distributed apps do usually seem to stick to their guidelines about public API.

Is this possible? If so - how? Merely changing the animation duration is not what I'm after. I'd like to have control over the animation curve too.

### Sample Code

See [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=25952359893792466772) for a playground attempting to do the above. Note that MKMapView seems to take the animation duration into account, but not the springiness, like Find my iPhone/Find my Friends.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? Maybe you missed something tiny there and someone will be able to correct it for you :)

Comment: @Losiowaty quite a few combinations which is why I didn't post code. I'm far from a newbie to iOS, I don't think I'm doing something simple wrong ;) good thought though, thanks for the comment

Comment: Not "simple", but "tiny" - a caveat of sorts ;] Nevertheless, showing what you tried will prevent answers with exactly that code :]

Comment: @Losiowaty see updated question, if you run the attached playground you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Well, could you post the code here? A lot of people, myself included, will not download arbitrary zip files for security reasons.

Comment: @Losiowaty umm... ok, wow. It's just a .playground file. If you don't wanna download, don't. Feel free to virus scan it. I don't like asking questions that are a page or two long (as less people bother to read/answer), hence code is attached. It is also a really quick way for someone to see/interact with the problem right away. No need to create their own project or anything. If that's not your thing feel free to move onto another question and help someone else out :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for AnimateWithDuration and use the UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut option. I did something similar in an app i created but with buttons. I had to chain animations together. Make it 100% of the intended size, then 80%, then back to 100%

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think .CurveEaseInOut is quite the animation curve I'm looking for - you're right though, I could chain animations - not a bad approach. Looking at Apple's implementation, I feel as though they may be getting a real spring animation to work, the private headers for MKMapView suggest that a spring animation is possible too, so I'll hold off on accepting this answer for now (incase there is a way to get a real spring type animation to register with MKMapView, as opposed to chained animations emulating a spring).